# Filtering junk mail in Outlook 2007 where sender is using my email address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, spam-prevention

I keep getting mail which I try to filter as junk. Problem is, it is sent from my e-mail address while writing that the name of the sender is "Viagra yada yada yada (myRealEmail@email.com)"

I can't add a rule to Outlook according to sender's name, right?

Is there any other way I can filter these spam e-mails (I can't add a rule to junk mail my own e-mail address)?

The subject of the e-mails keeps changing in the following formats:

- "Faruz 76% discount now!"
- "Faruz 80% discount now!"
- "Now! 78% discount Faruz"

(They seem to have infinite ideas of saying the same thing.)

So I also seem to have problems filtering according to subject.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, "Faruz" and "discount" appears in the subject of each spam email, you can filter them by keywords.

Comment: Sometimes they say instead of discount: "Free" or "off" or many other wonderous alternatives... couldn't find a decent pattern there